# How to cluster PyTorch predictions

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, cluster-analysis, knn

I'm trying to find road lanes from road images and then make predictions out of the images. So far, I've trained a model that finds road lanes. But most of the predictions are scattered. I'm trying to cluster PyTorch predictions that we get from these road images. These dots are the predictions of model where the road lanes might be.

Predictions shape: `[1, 1, 80, 120]`

Here's the image of predictions:

[image]

Here's what I want to achieve (I edited the image, deleted the dots that are scattered):

[image]

As you can see, I deleted the dots (predictions) from the image. I want each dot to be clustered with each other. How can I achieve this? I tried KNN (K Nearest Neighbors) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove dots then you can try to use [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) such as `Opening` (erode+dilate) to postprocess your mask.

The resulting mask without dots:

[image]

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

mask = cv2.imread('road_mask.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
mask = cv2.resize(mask, (120, 80))

mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((2, 2)))
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, np.ones((3, 3)))
mask = ((mask > 10) * 255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("postprocessed_mask.png", mask)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked on erasing scattered dots from the image.